# How can I add span with numbers after <h2>?

Tags: php

How can I add span with numbers after <h2>?

Please see my code below:

```
<pre>
<?php
$html='
    <h2>hello</h2>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <h2>good</h2>
    <p>godd day</p>
';

$nums=array(30,55);
// how can I replace $html and get result like this:
// put <span>xx</span> after </h2>
$html='
    <h2>hello</h2><span>30</span>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <h2>good</h2><span>55</span>
    <p>godd day</p>
';
```

Comment: preg_replace_callback() perhaps?

Comment: why do you want to replace, why not just create the $html directly as it should be? like is there a certain reason or you're just trying something out?

Comment: I use some function get the $html, the $html has no numbers , then I need to add extra nums base on the $html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mark Baker suggests in the comment, you could use `preg_replace_callback()` perharps.

```
$html='
    <h2>hello</h2>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <h2>good</h2>
    <p>godd day</p>
';

$nums=array(30,55);
$index = 0;

function add_number($match) {
    global $nums, $index;
    return $match[0]."<span>".(@$nums[$index++])."</span>";
}

echo preg_replace_callback("/\/h2>/","add_number",$html);
```

If you don't want to add the number twice, you can change the pattern to `/\/h2>(?!<span>)/`

Answer (score 0):

maybe use

```
foreach ( $nums as $key => $val ) { .. }
```

and generate $html.